# Ошибка загрузки спрайта, Allegro

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь загрузить спрайт и вывести его на экран при помощи библиотеки allegro:

```
#include <allegro.h>

int main()
{
    allegro_init();

    set_color_depth( 16 );

    install_keyboard();

    if ( set_gfx_mode( GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 640, 480, 0, 0 ) != 0 )
    {
        set_gfx_mode( GFX_TEXT, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        allegro_message( "Allegro error: %s", allegro_error );
        return -1;
    }

    BITMAP *sprite1;

    if ( !( sprite1 = load_bitmap( "sprite1.bmp", NULL ) ) )
    {
        set_gfx_mode( GFX_TEXT, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
        allegro_message( "Sprite error: %s", allegro_error );
        return -1;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Во время запуска программы я вижу сообщение "Sprite error:" (без вывода причины, то есть allegro_error). Спрайт находится в той же папке, что и исполняемый файл. В чём дело?

Comment: Я не против, могу задать заного, на русском языке. Просто я тут впервый раз, думал, что тут нет разницы.

Comment: На всякий случай, попробуйте прописать полный путь к файлу.

Comment: @ixSci Уже пытался (делал /home/user/sprite1.bmp)